# simple physics simulation meters and pixels conversions

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, physics, game-physics

I am building a simple physics simulation that invovles classical mechanic.
The user enter starting velocity and height and then there is an animation of a ball falling from this height.
I use the following formula (which is correct) :

y = y0 + v0t + 0.5at^2

the problem is even when the starting velocity is 100 meters/second , the ball still moves really slowly.

The reason may be that the ball moves in pixels and not meters. I can multiply the velocity by a big constant but the time will change. For example if it took 20 seconds to go 500meters, now it will take less and the user expect to see that the ball movement's time will be the same as the results from the physics formulas.

Comment: Between calculation and display you need a conversion from world coordinates (in meters) to display coordinates (in pixels9

Comment: Are you using `int`, `float` or `double` for your variables and how do you scale those values into pixels. What coordinate system do you use, and do you want to draw the trajectories slowly pixel by pixel or all at once (since you specify the shape in advance)? There isn't enough information here to effectively answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The only part where you work with meters versus pixels is when you're displaying the animation. The calculation doesn't change a bit. The only thing you should transform is `y` - to make it fit the screen as you require. Of course, both the size of the ball and the head need to get smaller on the display as you increase starting height :)

For example, if you've got a form that's 800 pixels tall, and you want to display a scene where a ball falls from 10 meters, the best you can do is use 80 pixels for each meter. That means that whenever you're drawing the ball, you have to multiply the `y` you got from your equation by `80`. Use `float`s :) Think of it as having to go further away from the scene to be able to see it all at once. Everything gets smaller to fit everything in frame. As a result, the bigger the drop height, the slower the ball will appear to move for the same initial velocity.